# Where to delete the Files which are stored locally in android?

Tags: android, file

I my application I am parsing one html file and storing in app local files directory.this I am  doing in onCreate(). Now their is one button "open",when I click the "open" button I am showing android chooser dialog by giving the path as files directory.

then in the onDestroy() I am deleting all the files which are stored in files directory.this is working upto 4.0.

but in 4.1 ,since once we open the chooser dialog ,it immediately calling onDestroy(). By the time another app (ex:Html viewer) tries to open the file ,file will not be available .so it is displaying file not found.so where to delete the local files?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
//Deleting the temperary folder and the file created in the sdcard
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) 
{
    if (dir.isDirectory()) 
    {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) 
        {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Put this code inside the `onDestroy()`

```
File checkFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/FolderName/");
//getting the control of sdcard files   
deleteDir(checkFile);
```

Comment: Thank u for reply.i am able to delete files,but where i need to delete the files(right now i am deleting in onDestroy(),but this will not help for me).is there any any method before killing the application?

Comment: but what ever the answers i got are not solving my questions.so how can i make as answered?
.

Comment: @ashokreddy Fine. Now i edited my answer. The above thing is working or not?

Comment: here the problem is deleting files in onDestroy().i should not delete in onDestroy().that is what i explained in question.

Comment: @ashokreddy It will work try my answer. Or put it in onStop()

Comment: i should not delete the files in onStop()/onDestroy(),bcz if i delete in onStop()/onDestroy() ,that file will not available to Chooser app(ex:Html Viewer).so i am asking to delete the files other than onStop()/onDestroy()?

Comment: With the above logic i am able to locate the local files .i am deleting all the files before storing new files in onCreate(),so that we don't need to delete files in onDestroy()/onStop().


Thank u.